# Display Tow logos , one in right side and one in left side and in between navbar + bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two logo's. One should be in the right corner and one should be in the left corner. But right logo is not displaying in the proper way.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="./" class="navbar-brand"><img src="applicatie/img/menu_icon.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="BB" height="50" width="50"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="home">
                <a href="./index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="bands">
                <a href="./bands.php">Bands</a>
            </li>
            <li id="jeugdhuizen">
                <a href="./jeugdhuizen.php">Jeugdhuizen</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="./phpBB3/index.php" target="_blank">Forum</a>
            </li>
            <li id="over">
                <a href="./over.php">Over Bandbook</a>
            </li>
            <li id="registreer">
                <a href="./signup.php">Registreer</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="loginoutform" role="form" action="./verwerklogin.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group" id="usernamediv">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="username">Username: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="passworddiv">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password: </label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="signin">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <a href="./" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><img src="applicatie/img/menu_icon.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="BB" height="50" width="50"></a>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS is :-

```
 .navbar-inverse { background-color: white;}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { background-color: #B84E1A}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { background-color: #912C13}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand { color: white; font: 42px playbill, onyx, fantasy; text-align: center; padding-top:0px;}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover { color: #B84E1A}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #999999}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}

   body
   {
       padding-top: 50px;
       background-color:#000000;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

umm.. like @Mrd05d said this seems to work

```
</ul>
<a href="./" class="navbar-brand pull-right">
<img src="applicatie/img/menu_icon.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="BB" height="50" width="50">
</a>
</nav><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

This will get the image all the way to the right but since its inside container it will still have some padding on the right side.

If you want it to be all the way to the top right (not aligned with menu at all) you can give it absolute positioning.

```
.logo-right{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You closed the nav before the second logo instead of after it...

```
</nav><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<a href="./" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><img src="applicatie/img/menu_icon.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="BB" height="50" width="50"></a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="./" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><img src="applicatie/img/menu_icon.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="BB" height="50" width="50"></a>
</nav><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: It does not go to the top-right corner. It is displaying next to the sign in button. I need to go the image at the end of the page top-right side .

Comment: Making the change above with the pull-right aligned the logo to the top right as you have asked: http://www.bootply.com/pBMJyYozkl If you are running out of horizontal space the second logo will bump the side of the container and be moved downward.